# Get simplified rotation of object

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

In my game, Im always rotating a gameobject (Cube) with Quaternion.Lerp. And I need which face of this cube is looking up. So I think I can use current rotation of object to get this (if there is a better way please say it).

Firstly this gameobject's rotation (0,0,0). when I rotate it forward it becomes (90,0,0). There is no problem. But after that, when I rotate it second time it doesnt become (180,0,0). it is (0,180,180). How can I prevent unity to do this.

Comment: You want to rotate it just in x axis always? What exactly you want to your rotation behaviour to do?

Comment: not always x axis, also z axis.

Answer (score 0):

Try using euler angles instead of quaternions, they are much simpler, here is an example:

```
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(180, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I need to use Quaternion.Lerp because I want a smooth rotating. And also, this is not an answer for my question.

Comment: For smooth rotating it doesn't matter which system do you use, you can script with whichever system you want. These kind of errors you are having could be solved with force setting eulerAngles, try it!

Comment: If you don't know to script your own interpolation try using iTween that is available for free on asset store.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of representing a rotation with Euler angles. When you convert the rotation of your GameObject (stored internally as a quaternion) to Euler angles (using either `transform.eulerAngles` or `transform.rotation.eulerAngles`) you may not get the result you're expecting.

You could get around this by storing a Vector3 (let's call it `currentRotation`) containing the rotation of your object in Euler angles, and construct Quaternions from it using [`Quaternion.Euler(currentRotation)`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html). You can do your interpolation by calculating your target rotation (`targetRotation`) as a Vector3, then constructing a Quaternion for it before doing `Quaternion.Lerp`:

```
var targetRotationQuaternion = Quaternion.Euler(targetRotation);
var currentRotationQuaternion = Quaternion.Euler(currentRotation);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(currentRotationQuaternion, targetRotationQuaternion, *your t*);
```

Incidentally, this answer is very similar to a comment on http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/667037/transformrotationeulerangles-not-accuarate.html but it's worth reproducing here in case that ever gets taken down.